# MySQL via SSH "Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails"

Tags: mysql, sql-server, ssh, foreign-keys, constraints

The full error message is:

> Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails
>   (`jpangil2/ACCOUNT`, CONSTRAINT `ACCOUNT_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`STU_GNUMBER`) REFERENCES `STUDENT` (`STU_GNUMBER`))

The two tables in question are STUDENT:

> mysql> CREATE TABLE STUDENT
>       -> (STU_GNUMBER INT(8) PRIMARY KEY,
>       -> STU_LNAME CHAR(50),
>       -> STU_FNAME CHAR(50),
>       -> STU_EMAIL CHAR(50),
>       -> STU_DOB DATE,
>       -> STU_PHONE CHAR(10),
>       -> DEP_ID INT(8)
>       -> FOREIGN KEY(DEP_ID)
>       -> REFERENCES DEPENDENT(DEP_ID));

And ACCOUNT:

> mysql> CREATE TABLE ACCOUNT
>       -> (ACC_NUMBER INT(8) PRIMARY KEY,
>       -> STU_GNUMBER INT(8),
>       -> PO_NUMBER INT(8),
>       -> SL_NUMBER INT(8),
>       -> TU_NUMBER INT(9),
>       -> BSS_NUMBER INT(8),
>       -> MHA_NUMBER INT(8),
>       -> FOREIGN KEY(STU_GNUMBER) REFERENCES STUDENT(STU_GNUMBER) );

When I try to add records in ACCOUNT table and the column "STU_GNUMBER" with (12345678) for example, I get the above error message. I've looked everywhere on this site for similar questions, but the answers that I do find talk about PHP, show create table and other commands, and other advanced SQL logic that my novice skill can't understand. I'm using my university's MySQL through Secure Shell and VPN, so I don't see how these PHP answers help me. :/

I've already received help from others online with no luck, but can someone please help me who don't condescend me at every post or beat me down because I can't understand some higher level SQL commands and logic? Thank you and you have my sincerest gratitude to those who do.

Answer (score 0):

With the tables you provided, an `account` references a `student` - you cannot have an account that refer (= has a value in `stu_gnumber` that does not exist. This is the meaning of the foreign key declared on the table.

In order to insert a new row into `account`, you must have a valid value for `stu_gnumber` - either a preexisting one which you retrieved by querying the table, or by inserting a new record there before instering the new record to `account` (if, e.g., your application is creating a new `student` and `account` together).

Note that this issue is unrelated to the ssh you're using - it comes from the underlying table structure and the order of your `insert`s, regardless of the transport layer specifics.